# Serving plain-text SVGs with Express.js (Solution related to Cheerio.js)

Tags: html, css, node.js, express, svg

I am trying to process SVGs prior to sending them via Express.js.  I have the following code:

```
app.get("/iconic/styles/:style/:base/:icon", function (req, res) {
    var style = req.params.style;
    var base = req.params.base;
    var icon = req.params.icon;

    var iconPath = path.join(iconFolderRoot, style, icon);

    svgProcessor(iconPath, base).then(function (svg) {
        //console.log(svg);  // SO: See the example output posted below

        res.header("Content-Type","image/svg+xml");

        //res.send(new Buffer(svg, 'binary')); // No difference

        res.send(svg);
    }).catch(function (err) {
        res.status(404).send("Error" + JSON.stringify(err, null, "  "));
    });
});
```

Without setting the `res.header()`, I can visit the route in the browser and it behaves as expected (scales to fit).  Unfortunately, I can't embed them in an `<img>` tag unless the header is set.

With `res.header()` set, I can embed the image in an `<img>` tag, but it doesn't behave as I would expect (static size).

Sending the file directly with `res.sendFile(iconPath)` works correctly.  I wondered if this was because the file needed to be sent as a binary which can be seen in `res.send(new Buffer(svg, 'binary'))` but this had the same effect as `res.send(svg)`.

The statement `console.log(svg)` outputs the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.2.1, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewbox="0 0 128 128" style="enable-background:new 0 0 128 128;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
        .st0{fill:#49C5B1;}
</style>
<title>Icons_TEST</title>
<g id="Example">
        <path {{{REMOVED FOR STACKOVERFLOW POST}}}/>
</g>
</svg>
```

I can think of a workaround which would be to save the file to a temp directory and using the `res.sendFile(tempPath)`, but there has to be a better way...

Here is a sample of the response header:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Content-Type: image/svg+xml
Date: Thu, 20 Oct 2016 00:51:18 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 3577
```

Comment: what about this: <img src="url-to-svg" onerror="this.onerror=null; this.src='fallback-image.png'"> or just background-image of some div ?

Comment: @num8er, The SVGs are rendering, they just don't behave like SVGs (scaling in any way.  They are a static size unresponsive to CSS).  Also, unless the fallback image was dynamically generated, it would defeat the purpose of what I'm trying to achieve - dynamically processed icons.

Comment: I think You should convert svg dynamically to png on serverside and to not make a heavy load on server just to cache the result of convertion.

Answer (score 2):

After posing this question in the Express github page, a user indicated that they were curious about the svgProcessor as a potential problem.  Believing that the problem was related to the way it was being served, I tried to eliminate this as a potential cause by rendering the svg directly with `res.render(fs.readFileSync(iconPath))`.  To my surprise, this actually rendered as expected.

I stared at the output from the svgProcessor for a long period of time and couldn't see the difference so I ran it through an online diffing tool and it showed the following:

[image]

Even with the answer right in front of me, I still didn't see what the problem was.  Then I realized, the `B` in `viewBox` was being lower-cased!  This was due to a package called Cheerio (which I was using for traversing the svg nodes) normalizing the attributes.

Solution: `var $ = cheerio.load(svg, { xmlMode: true } );`